# Did Snape create/discover the spell "Sectumsempra"?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, severus-snape

Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollows:

> "He lost his hood during the chase. Sectumsempra was always a
>   specialty of Snape's. I wish I could say I'd paid him back in kind,
>   but it was all I could do to keep George on the broom after he was
>   injured, he was losing so much blood."

I always thought that Snape discovered/created this spell. The spell was handwritten in the Half Blood Prince's textbook. I also thought I remembered reading it somewhere.

Also in the movie Snape criticizes Harry when he tries to use it against Snape and tells Harry, "You dare try to use my own spell against me?" This implies it's Snape's spell.

But the passage above implies that it was a prefered spell of Snape's as opposed to something he created.

Was this a generally known spell that Snape used, or was it something that he created?

Comment: @Richard is this a dupe? That question was whether spells could be created by wizards in general. We know that wizards can create spells, otherwise how were the first spells created. In addition there's so many examples of wizards creating spells, that again it's not even a question that would come to mind. My question is very specific. I used an in-canon quote from the book, and the question is framed perfectly. I want to know if you agree or not and want to lodge a formal complaint against this user. I'd like to know how to do so.

Comment: @Richard at best a comment or "A possible answer" could have been done(there wasn't one). Also the other question should have been framed better. A better question would be how did spells originate and are they created or discovered. The question and the answers are sub-standard in my opinion and I would guess in your mind as well.

Comment: Not sure why you're asking Richard about this since he didn't close it...  In any case, the standard for duplicates on SE is that if the answers to the other question also answer this, then this is a duplicate.  The answers to the other question make it pretty clear Snape created the spell.

Comment: @JMFB - There is no formal complaint procedure on the site, nor do I believe there's any case to answer. If you **keep** asking duplicate Harry Potter questions, you'll **keep** getting them closed by slytherincess (and DVK) since they're the gold tag badge holders in that tag.

Comment: I think that Snape created Sectumsempra, but that wouldn't prevent it from becoming his "speciality"...